# During the Dominion War, why do they keep saying the entire quadrant is at stake?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-dominion

Why do they always say the entire quadrant is at stake, when obviously the entire Federation combined with the Romulans, the Klingons, the Cardassians, the Breen, and the Ferengi is still a small fraction of the Alpha quadrant.

Comment: You think the Founders would simply stop, once they dealt with the federation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're absolutely right. The quadrants of the galaxy are very large and the superpowers of the Alpha Quadrant represent only a very small proportion of that space. On top of that, the Federation is continually discovering entire solar empires *within* their own borders, so they can't even claim to be fighting for the whole of their own territory, let alone on behalf of the entire Alpha Quadrant.

What you're looking at here is a mixture of [hyperbole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole) and simplification. Assuming the Dominion force can flood freely through the wormhole, it's likely that once they've dominated the Federation, Klingons and Romulans that they'll attack other states outside the current known territories of the Alpha quadrant superpowers.

[image]

<sub><sup>Map courtesy of [Star Trek: Star Charts](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0743437705)</sup></sub>

Comment: A source for that image would be nice... especially since I'm about 90% sure there are no official maps of that quality.

Comment: @Kevin - The updated version of Star Trek: Star Charts includes a dedication thanking numerous members of the ST Art and Production team for their assistance in reviewing the book. Although it's considered to be *non-canon* (Paramount licensed, but not an official tie-in product), it seems fairly likely that at least one of the people who reviewed the book would have taken issue with the political map shown if it was wildly inaccurate.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, for the same reasons people today often say that global warming will destroy the planet when it's really the biosphere (in its current form) that's on the line.